# % Allocation in MS Project gantt view

Tags: ms-project

I have an issue with MS Project right now. We have several Gantts which we would like to see the % Allocation of a person in a separate column. In the Resource Usage view it is possible to show a field called "Remaining Availability" but that only shows in hours not % allocation. Could someone please explain how I can create a column in the Gantt or the Resource Usage view (preferably Resource Usage view) which then contains the information on the % allocation of that particular person to that project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field called [Percent Allocation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Percent-Allocation-fields-b8d25634-1bf4-4d29-b568-7f637f37a46f), but it is a timephased field. You can display it in the timephased grid on the right of the resource usage view.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :-)